# joining two table and result come twice in result

Tags: sql, join

i have a select command in my query that fetch data from two table , and each row of result come  twice in result , my query is

```
Select  
  Driver.DriverID,
  Driver.FName,
  Driver.LName,
  Driver.SmartCardNumber,
  Driver.DriverState,
  Driver.DriverCity,
  Driver.DriverAddress,
  Driver.Mobile,
  Driver.Telephone,
  Driver.MelliCardNumber, 
  Driver.CertificatePublisher,
  Driver.addeddate,
  Driver.ContractorID,
  Driver.editeddate,
  Contractor.name  
From Driver,Contractor
```

Answer (score 3):

you need where condition if Driver and Contractor tables have relationship between them.

something like

```
Select  
  Driver.DriverID,
  Driver.FName,
  Driver.LName,
  Driver.SmartCardNumber,
  Driver.DriverState,
  Driver.DriverCity,
  Driver.DriverAddress,
  Driver.Mobile,
  Driver.Telephone,
  Driver.MelliCardNumber, 
  Driver.CertificatePublisher,
  Driver.addeddate,
  Driver.ContractorID,
  Driver.editeddate,
  Contractor.name  
From Driver,Contractor
    where Driver.ContractorID = Contractor.id
```

assuming ContractorID is linked to the id of Contractor.

Comment: probably `Driver.ContractorID` based on his query

Answer (score 0):

You can try use DISTINCT.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  Driver.DriverID,
Driver.FName,
Driver.LName,
Driver.SmartCardNumber,
Driver.DriverState,
Driver.DriverCity,
Driver.DriverAddress,
Driver.Mobile,
Driver.Telephone,
Driver.MelliCardNumber,
Driver.CertificatePublisher,
Driver.addeddate,
Driver.ContractorID,
Driver.editeddate,
Contractor.name  

From Driver,Contractor
```

Or if you don't need a CROSS result, then you can try to make a LEFT or INNER JOIN if you have a reference between the two table

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the dbms how to join the records from the 2 tables:

For instance

```
Select 
  Driver.DriverID,
  Driver.FName,
  ...,
  Contractor.name  
  From Driver,Contractor
  Where Driver.ContractorID = Contractor.ID;
```

Or

```
Select 
  Driver.DriverID,
  Driver.FName,
  ...,
  Contractor.name  
  From Driver inner join Contractor
  On Driver.ContractorID = Contractor.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select  Driver.DriverID,
Driver.FName,
Driver.LName,
Driver.SmartCardNumber,
Driver.DriverState,
Driver.DriverCity,
Driver.DriverAddress,
Driver.Mobile,
Driver.Telephone,
Driver.MelliCardNumber,
Driver.CertificatePublisher,
Driver.addeddate,
Driver.ContractorID,
Driver.editeddate,
Contractor.name  
From Driver,Contractor
where Driver.DriverId=Contractor.DriverId;
```

(mention some condition like this to fetch data)